# WPF different window layouts per window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am still fairly new to WPF and I was wondering if it is possible to apply different layouts to diferrent windows, let me explain my scenario.

I have a WPF application which is using MVVM and Caliburn Micro and I have a ShellView (Window) and ShellViewModel (Conductor) in my main application which is launched on start, this has a specific layout.  What I am wanting to achieve is the ability to open a new window which is for application Administration, so the view will be called let's say AdminShellView (Window) and the AdminShellViewModel (Conductor).

Now currently when I run my application and open the AdminShellViewModel using the IWindowManager it is loading with the same layout as the ShellView.

How is it possible to apply a different layout and design to these two windows please?

Comment: Two views and single viewmodel (suplimenting either of the view) might be an option. I myself prefer a *mutating* view where admin options are invisible and appears as soon as some property (`IsAdminLogged`) changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Caliburn Micro myself but I believe you should be able to achieve this by loading different controls to your main window (Admin and nonAdmin)- in your case the ShellView. You could then bind each control to each own viewmodel or to ShellViewModel, whichever is more conveninet to you.

Comment: I do the content of the window as UserControls, but this is about layout of the window itself

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it would be to use a ContentPresenter in your window and then define the resources for it.

I also like to keep my Views as controls so I usually define them as a UserControl so I can create dynamic UI's without having to keep creating new windows.  Just swap out the content based on the view model.

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="mainContent">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AdminShellViewModel}">
            <views:AdminShellView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- We can also define more -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ShellViewModel}">
            <views:ShellView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: What about styling the window itself, so my ShellView is a custom border less window, command buttons, title, etc. For the admin window I want a different window design, eg. Menu button top left, larger title bar height and action buttons on the title bar. I tried creating another window and styling that but that seems like duplication